# How to find out the maximum number of datafiles per tablespace in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, tablespaces, datafile

According to this [Oracle document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits002.htm#i287915), the maximum number of database files per tablespace is "Operating system dependent; usually 1022".

I know there are queries for some of the other limits mentioned in that document (e.g. to determine the database block size: `select value from v$parameter where name='db_block_size'`).

Is there a query to determine the maximum number of datafiles per tablespace?  (I tried `select name from v$parameter where value='1022'` but that returned no rows.)

Comment: I guess that you can have lower limit on some exotic operating systems which support less than 1022 files on the filesystem. In all "normal" cases limit is 1022. But once again that's a guess.

Comment: It is probably contained in some variable, but may not be accessible. MOS note 262384.1 may provide some more light on this.

Answer (score -1):

`db block size` is a database parameter but maximum number of tablespace or datafile is a physical limit and you can not find them in `v$parameter` view. You can use documentation for that: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits002.htm#i287915

Answer (score -2):

Use:

select count(1),tablespace_name from dba_data_files group by tablespace_name

If getting close to 1022, you need to start moving the largest and fastest growing objects to different tablespaces.  32TB is the max with a 8k block size, 16k you can get 64 TB and with 32k 128 TB for the max.  However, the larger the block size the more likely you could get hot blocks, so need to think about how they would be used.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

```
 select count(*) from dba_data_files where tablespace_name='TBSNAME';
```

Comment: Does this give the *maximum* number of datafiles or the *actual* number of datafiles?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.